# PHP Mailer - email não chega na caixa de entrada

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, envio-de-email

Comecei a usar o phpmailer pelo proprio exemplo da página do git, dá tudo ok, o echo vai para "mensage enviada", mas a mensagem não chega na caixa de email, alguem sabe dizer porque?

```
<?php

require './PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require './PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require './PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
try {

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Username = 'cairoofelipe@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = '******';
$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->setFrom('cairoofelipe@gmail.com', 'Cairo');
$mail->addAddress('yarapinheiro.a@gmail.com', 'Yara');
$mail->addReplyTo('cairoofelipe@gmail.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cairoofelipe@gmail.com');
$mail->addBCC('cairoofelipe@gmail.com');

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

$mail->send();
echo 'Message enviada';
 } catch (Exception $e) {
 echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
} 
?>
```

Comment: E na caixa de spam?

Comment: também não chegou

Comment: tem algo a ver em está em um servidor local? e não dentro de uma hospedagem

Comment: Dá uma olhada na caixa de entrada do email remetente e veja se retornou alguma coisa.

Comment: retornou nada mano

Comment: Tem um lugar no google que vc tem que dar permissão a aplicativos de acessar a sua conta. Só não lembro agora onde é isso.

Comment: Esse aqui @Sam? [Permitir que apps menos seguros usem sua conta](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=pt-BR) e [Permitir que apps menos seguros usem sua conta(Administrador)](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra enviar e-mails você tem que ativar a opção de permitir que aplicativos menos seguros usem a conta.
Para ativar essa opção clique na imagem do seu perfil do gmail, clique em "conta do google"
[image]

Depois no menu do lado esquerdo clique em "segurança"
[image: Passo2]

Depois role a pagina até achar a opção "acesso a app menos seguro" e clique em "ativar acesso"
[image: Passo3]
 creio que com isso já consiga enviar os emails

Comment: Organize melhor sua resposta. Coloque umas imagens das páginas e de onde deve clicar.